# Converting an image_tag into a link that goes to the destroy route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to convert this line of code into a link that goes to the destroy route in my routes table.  When this picture is pressed it will delete the current photo.

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.avatarpic %>
```

The route is as follows:

```
user_avatar DELETE /users/:user_id/avatars/:id(.:format) avatars#destroy
```

The Avatar controller is as follow:

```
class AvatarsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @avatar = Avatar.new(avatar_params)
    @avatar.user = @user
    @avatar.save
    # Three lines above can be replaced with 
    # @user.create_avatar(params)
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

private

def avatar_params
  params.require(:avatar).permit(:avatarpic)
end

end
```

Currently I have an if/else statement that will display a default image if an avatar photo isn't available:

```
<% if @user.avatar.present? %>
  <%= image_tag @user.avatar.avatarpic %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag 'user.png' %>
  <a href="#" class="add-image" data-toggle="modal" data-
  target="#avatarpic">
    Add a Picture
  </a>
<% end %>
```

I would also like for a message to display once the mouse is hovering over the current avatar photo.  It will say something to the effect of "Upload a different image".  Once pressed, there should be a warning that asks the user "Are you sure you would like to delete this image?".  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the route you give above, please try this:

```
<%= link_to user_avatar_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure' } do %>
  <%= image_tag @user.avatar.avatarpic %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: <%= link_to user_avatar_path(@user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure' } do %>
  <%= image_tag @user.avatar.avatarpic %>
<% end %>

works

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in front of my PC but this should work:

```
<%= link_to destroy_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
   <%= image_tag @user.avatar.avatarpic %>
<% end %>
```

Please try and let me know if it does.

Comment: Add in `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } `

Comment: Thanks @jemonsanto. Edited the answer to include the data confirmation.

Comment: <%= link_to user_avatar_path(@user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure' } do %> <%= image_tag @user.avatar.avatarpic %> <% end %> works 
You are basically right.

Comment: Great. Well, an answer is already accepted so could you please upvote this :)